# google links showing sitemap and generating 404 errors I can't explain

Tags: sitemap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbIU1.jpg)I created a new website https://www.safedoor.co.uk for a company. It used to be a WordPress site now just plain javascript and html5. Generally, it works fine. Old Google links are bringing up the new sitemap but generating the old links and it's causing 404 errors. I need some help as this is the first time it's happened to me. The client wanted to maintain certain links, but other paths have been changed due to a new site structure. Is this a Google Crawl and cache issue? Will it go away after time when Google has crawled it a few times, or do I have to do something very specific with Google webmasters that I am not familiar with?[example of errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1WvQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include a concrete technical question. Currently you've no code but only a dead link, so the question can't be answered. Without editing the question will be candidate for being closed. You can read here [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Thanks!

Comment: As I am a new user I am not allowed to add images. The dead link is supposed to be a link to a screen shot of a google search. As it is evidence of a google search I cannot provide a code problem as this is not my issue it is a result of changing the website but maintaining some of the old urls that have casue the problem I am just looking for some confirmation as to why this happens.

Comment: If the problem is related to links that are not existing anymore but still to the same server, search (also here on Stack Overflow) for `Redirect` in combination with your type of server (`Nginx`,  `Apache`, ...).
The dead link is related to a non-serving server and not to this portal. Also the image you uploaded here, can be seen. So in general you could improve your question.